# Using a company like NameCheap how can I point a domain to a subfolder of another hosting company

Tags: .htaccess, dns, hosting

I have a domain AAA.us that I want pointed to BBB.com/subfolder (NOT REDIRECTED)
So if I went to AAA.us/index.html?r=5 that I am really seeing content under BBB.com/subfolder/index.html?r=5 but the url is still AAA.us/index.html?r=5?

I have currently set an A record for AAA.us to point at BBB.com and then a htaccess redirect to rewrite anything for AAA.us (see below)

Is this the best way or is there a better way?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.AAA.us$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/AAA/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/AAA/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^AAA.us$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/AAA/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/AAA/$1
```

Comment: oh and this doesn't work with subdomains for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember that when you assign an A record to any hosting company, you are assigning it to an IP that is own by that hosting company.  In my case, webfusion.co.uk, which is probably typical, this one IP is to a load balancing switch into farm of LAMP servers.  The actual user directories are served by NAS fabric interconnected to the LAMP server farm via 100Mb Enet switch or Brocade-stysle fabric.  The whole think is designed to scale smoothly to tens of thousands of accounts / domains.  So any individual server could receive 100s or 1,000s of different HTTP_HOST requests.

This type of configuration doesn't use a standard Apache vhost type of configuration as this doesn't scale to this level.  Typically they use a RewriteMap to some caching lookup `prg` which ultimately looks up each domain in a central configuration D/B.  If you've not registered **AAA** with your hosting provider as a domain that you own and the target directory that you want it to map to, then the hosting provider will dump this inbound request or redirect to some vanilla home page.

Some host providers offer this as a free service, some do it for a one-off configuration free and some for a monthly fee.  Exactly which depends on the provider, and this is a dialogue that you are going to have to have.

Alternatively you can just set yourself up an Amazon EC2 microinstance, if you know how to admin a Linux VM from SSH and configure the vhosts yourself -- but this might cost more than a typical shared hosting offering.

Comment: thanks Terry but the domain is through namecheap and is hosted on GoDaddy

Comment: So? What's your point? GoDaddy is configured just as I describe.  How have you configured your GoDaddy account so that the infrastructure knows where to map `GET /` requests for HTTP HOST **AAA*** in your GoDaddy file space?

Comment: I'm not sure they have a DNS manager but it seems limited.  We are a shared hosting not a VPS.  I really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Chris we are still talking at cross purposes. Answer these Qs: (i) Have you registered **AAA** with GoDaddy as belonging to you? If so (b) in this registration process, can you specify a sub-directory?  If not then Godaddy will not direct _any_ HTTP://AAA/xxx requests to your directory tree

Comment: No AAA is at Namecheap 
I understand what you are saying with the normal godaddy process but that is only if we purchase the domain through them. Normally on namecheap you would create an A record with the godaddys servers Ip address but when we add a subfolder that doesn't work

Comment: Chris, you still don't get it do you?

Comment: I ***know*** that the DNS record is with Namecheap, but when GoDaddy receives a `GET /something`, it won't know what to do with a request header `Host: AAA` and so it will dump it.  Your IP isn't unique to you.  You share it will hundreds of other accounts.  You need to register _any_ domains that you use as per [Managing Your Hosting Account Domains](http://help.godaddy.com/article/4688#add) --- Duuuuurrrr!

Comment: I was finally able to get someone at Godaddy that knew something and they were able to show me the place it had to be changed....    Sorry for the run around...